# input file empty handling

Tags: php, html, forms

So, i have a form, it is article form where there is title, content,image(for showing selected image from input by using javascript) and input(to select the image), and i use

```
$upload_errors = array(
    // http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php
    UPLOAD_ERR_OK               => "No errors.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE     => "Larger than upload_max_filesize.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE  => "Larger than form MAX_FILE_SIZE.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL        => "Partial upload.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE        => "No file.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR => "No temporary directory.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE => "Can't write to disk.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION  => "File upload stopped by extension."
);
```

to check if my input file having error and it works fine for adding new article...

But, what if i want to edit my article? normally i will reuse the same form but echo the selected article value and all shown, it show title,content,image but not with input file and i know it is security issue, so for example i want just to change the article title, i will get error "No file" since i submit all my form content including input file... so is there any best practice for this kind of problem? maybe some way to indentify if i not select any image then i will just pass it and not showing any error...

and here is how i handle the error

```
$error = $_FILES['upload_file']['error'];
if ($error != 1) {
    $information->id = $_POST['id'];  
    $information->name = $_POST['name'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $information->upload_image($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name']);

    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $entity_content = htmlentities($content);
    $entity_content = stripslashes(str_replace('\r\n', '',$entity_content));
    $information->content = $entity_content;
    try{
        if($information->save()){
            if(isset($_POST['simpan'])){
                redirect_to("show_information.php");
            }
        }else{
            $message = "failed to change information";
        }
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        $message = "failed to change information";
        error_notice($e);
    } 
}else{
    $message = $upload_errors[$error];
}
```

so what do i need to do to bypass the error check if there is no input?

Comment: you could add a checkbox and if its checked you run a different error block else run the one above maybe?

Comment: In your test, check if the article already exists; if so, forget about the input file: ``if ($error != 1 or article_exists($_POST['id']) === true)`` assuming ``article_exists()`` returns ``true`` if the article exists. Don't ``upload_image()`` in such case.

Comment: so there is no way to handle it without adding checkbox or something into my form? i just thinking a simplest way for user to use my web form.... :(

Answer (score 0):

so i just get the best solution for this.... it is actually very easy

```
$error = $_FILES['upload_file']['error']; 
if ($error == 0 || $error == 4) {
     if($error != 4)
     //do the uploading
}
```

and in my upload/save class i just need to check

```
if(!empty($image))
   // do move_uploaded_to 
   // do the saving with replacement of $image
else
   // do the saving without $image
```

$image is just my placeholder to put image name/path to mysql database